# Multiple simultaneous button animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to create an animation for a button on click event. A simple function which simply consists on toggling  classes and setting timeouts is used for the animation.

It works well for one button but when I have more than one button and I click two or more of them consecutively before the animation is finished, the animation stops and continues on the element which has been clicked later.

So the problem is to make the animation function to refer to the object which has triggered it, therefore creating multiple instances of it, for which I haven't been able to find a simple solution after hours of search).

Thanks in advance.

There's a simplified example (real example has more classes toggles):

```
$('.myButton').on('click', animateButton);
function animateButton(){

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('animate');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('animate');
  },2000)

}
```

EDIT: I've made a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/8ozu14am/

EDIT2: SOLVED

Using $.proxy() it is possible to maintain the context.

```
$('.myButton').on('click', animateButton);
function animateButton(){

  $(this).addClass('animate');

  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
  },this),2000)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Using $.proxy() it is possible to maintain the context.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

```
$('.myButton').on('click', animateButton);
function animateButton(){

  $(this).addClass('animate');

  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
  },this),2000)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery return an [Event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) to your handler.

It have the property `target`which is the DOM element that initiated the event.

```
$('.myButton').on('click', animateButton);
function animateButton(evt){

  var $this = $(evt.target);
  $this.addClass('animate');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('animate');
  },2000)

}
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle short example so I can se emore exactly what you are dealing with ?